# How to run stored procedure on SQL server from Spark (Databricks) JDBC python?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, databricks

I have a working example of executing a stored procedure in a SQL SERVER with the below Scala code in Databricks. But I'm wondring if it is possible to do the same in Python JDBC? I cannot make it work. Please see examples below:

**WORKING code in SCALA**

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType,IntegerType};
import java.sql.ResultSet

val username = "xxxxx"
val pass = "xxxxx"
val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=xxx"
val table = "SalesLT.Temp3"
val query = s"EXEC sp_truncate_table '${table}'"

val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass)
val rs = conn.createStatement.execute(query)
```

**Python Code so far**

```
connector_type_sql_server_driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_hostname = "xxxx.database.windows.net"
jdbc_database = "xxxx"
jdbc_port = 1433
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbc_hostname}:{jdbc_port};database={jdbc_database}"
jdbc_spa_user = "xxx"
jdbc_spa_password = "xxx"


query = "EXEC sys.sp_tables"
query2 = "SELECT * FROM sys.tables"

jdbc_db = (spark.read
          .format("jdbc")
          .option("driver", connector_type_sql_server_driver)
          .option("url", jdbc_url)
          .option("query", query)
          .option("user", jdbc_spa_user)
          .option("password", jdbc_spa_password)
          .load()
          )
```

query2 in python is working, but anything starting with EXEC does not seem to work...

If it is not possible can someone explain in detail why it can be done in Scala and not in Python in databricks? I want to make it work with Python because the rest of the notebooks are in Python already..

Thank you.

/Baatch

Comment: _does not seem to work_ means absolutely nothing. Please explain why it is not functioning as expected. If an error is returned _post the error_

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible you just need to get access to the underlying Java classes of JDBC, something like this:

```py
# the first line is the main entry point into JDBC world
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(mssql_url, mssql_user, mssql_pass)
connection.prepareCall("EXEC sys.sp_tables").execute()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Alex - It works as expected. However, if one wants to read the rows returned by the Stored Procedure how will one code it?

Comment: just follow JDBC documentation, specially Listing 6.7: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html

Comment: @AlexOtt How can we do it using `Apache Spark Connector` - a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72092252/1232087).

Comment: see as well https://medium.com/delaware-pro/executing-ddl-statements-stored-procedures-on-sql-server-using-pyspark-in-databricks-2b31d9276811

Comment: Can someone please letme know how to capture the output of the stored procedures  , like DataFrame or Integer or String from the Stored Procedure

Comment: @AlexOtt link is broken